# How to determine if one digit in the user's lottery pick matches a digit in the lottery number?

Tags: c, loops, random, boolean

> Problem:
> Write a c program that will allow the user to play Lottery for as long as he/she wanted to. The program
> randomly generates a lottery of a two-digit number, prompts the user to enter a pick of two-digit
> number, and determines whether the user wins according to the following rules:
>
> 1. If the user’s pick matches the lottery number in the exact order, the prize at stake is P8,000.
> 2. If all digits in the user’s pick match all digits in the lottery number, the prize at stake is P5,000.
> 3. If one digit in the user’s pick matches a digit in the lottery number, the prize at stake is P2,000.
>
> Required knowledge: Generating random numbers, comparing digits, using Boolean operators, selection
> and looping structures.

I'm stuck on the third requirement — can you help?

This is my code so far...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    int guess, guess2, lottoNum2, lottoNum3, lottoNum4, ones;
    int lottoNum = rand() % 100;

    printf("The lottery number is %d\n", lottoNum);

    printf("Enter your lottery pick (two digits): ");
    scanf("%d", &guess);

    if (guess == lottoNum)
        printf("\nExact match: you win P8,000");

    while (lottoNum != 0)
    {
        ones = lottoNum % 10;
        lottoNum2 = lottoNum2 * 10 + ones;
        lottoNum /= 10;
    }
    if (guess == lottoNum2)
        printf("\nMatch all digits: you win P5000\n");

    while (lottoNum != 0)
    {
       

    if (guess != lottoNum)
    printf("\nSorry, there is no digit match!");
}
```

Comment: Could you share a test case for what you need in each requirement? For number one I get it if program randomizes 42 and you guess 42 then you win P8,000 which is exact match. Could you give an example for requirement 2 and 3?

Comment: Test Cases
Case 1 (For a sample lottery number 90)
Enter your lottery pick (two digits): 90
Exact match: You win P8,000
Case 2 (For a sample lottery number 56)
Enter your lottery pick (two digits): 65
Match all digits: you win P5,000
Case 3 (For a sample lottery number 13)
Enter your lottery pick: 53
Match one digit: you win P2,000
Case 4 (For a sample lottery number 56)
Enter your lottery pick: 12
Sorry, there is no digit match!

Comment: And will you only need it to work for 2 numbers or for any amount of digits?

Comment: 1 two-digit number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int first_digit();
int second_digit();

int main()
{
    int key = 1;
    while(key!=0){
        
        srand((unsigned)time(0));
        int guess=0;
        int temp=0;
        int lottoNum = rand() % 100;
    
        printf("The lottery number is %d\n", lottoNum);
        scanf("%d", &guess);
        
        int guess_digit1=0, guess_digit2=0, lotto_digit1=0, lotto_digit2=0;
    
        guess_digit2 = guess%10;
        guess_digit1 = (guess - guess_digit2) / 10;
        
        lotto_digit2 = lottoNum%10;
        lotto_digit1 = (lottoNum - lotto_digit1) / 10;
        
       
        int sentinel = 1; //sentinel=1 game on | sentinel=0 game over
        
        if (guess == lottoNum){
            printf("\nExact match: you win P8,000");
            sentinel = 0;
        }
           
        if((lotto_digit1 == guess_digit2) && (lotto_digit2 == guess_digit1) && sentinel==1){
            printf("\nMatch all digits: you win P5000\n");
            sentinel = 0;
        }
        
        if((guess_digit1 != lotto_digit1 && guess_digit1 != lotto_digit2)  && sentinel==1){
            if((guess_digit2 != lotto_digit1 && guess_digit2 != lotto_digit2) && sentinel==1){
                printf("\nSorry, there is no digit match!");
            }else{
                if(sentinel==1)
                    printf("\nMatch 1 digit: you win P2000\n"); 
            }
        }else{
            if(sentinel==1)
                printf("\nMatch 1 digit: you win P2000\n");
            
        }
        
        printf("\nKeep playing? Press 0 to exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &key);
        sentinel = 1;
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

There were some things wrong with the code you posted, and was correcting each one of them but it was too much so I just coded it from 0. But if you are interested to know what was wrong eitherway here's some clarifications of your code:

First, include `time.h` so that you don't get warnings or errors in your time() function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> // <-- add this
```

The issue you are having with the **P5000** requirement is because `lottoNum2` is not initialized when you multiply it by 10. By default C takes a part of memory that inevitably contains binary code within it, causing `lottoNum2` to have a random value when called. To correct this, initialize lottoNum2 to 0:

```
int guess, guess2, lottoNum2=0; <-- this.
```

From this point, the variables `lottoNum3` and `lottoNum4` are called but never used. So you can erase them.

Then for your last requirement, first thing I notice is that there is a missing bracket for your `while` statement:

```
    while (lottoNum != 0)
    {
        if (guess != lottoNum)
        printf("\nSorry, there is no digit match!");

    } // <----- add this!
}
```

Because you altered the original value of `lottoNum` during your previous while loop (performing `lottoNum /= 10;` you don't have a place where you can ask for what was the number at the third requirement. So I suggest using a temporary variable just to perform second requirement:

```
temp = lottoNum;
while (temp != 0)
{
    ones = temp % 10;
    lottoNum2 = lottoNum2 * 10 + ones;
    temp /= 10;
}

// At this point you still have lottoNum information!
```

At this point I guess to keep going with that code you would have to also loop your guess to see if any number matches but it's not necesary for only 2 digit numbers. You can calculate it straight away.

Answer (score 0):

It was simpler just to break it into ones and tens digits rather than try and put it back together. You'll need to do that for checking if their is any matches at all so why not use it for the entire thing.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int guess=0;
    while(1){
        int lotto = rand()%90 + 10;
        //Creates 2 digit number
        int l_1 = lotto%10;
        int l_10 = lotto/10;
        printf("Lotto# %d\n",lotto);
        printf("Enter 100 to quit");
        printf("Enter a 2 digit number:");
        scanf("%d",&guess);
        int g_1= guess%10;
        int g_10 = guess/10;
        if(guess==100)break;
        if(g_1==l_1 && g_10==l_10){
            printf("Exact match: You win P8000\n");
        }
        else if(g_1==l_10 && g_10==l_1){
            printf("All numbers matched: You win P5000\n");
        }
        else if(g_1==l_1 || g_10==l_10 || g_1==l_10 || g_10==l_1){
            printf("One number matched: You win P2000\n");
        }
        else {printf("You lost no numbers matched\n");}
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you :D you made the code easier to read.